# Angular directive's controller initialized twice

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I have a project based on https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-sidemenu

I made a directive *rsNotification* for handle upcoming MQTT messages

**rsNotification.js**

```
    (function (angular) {
    console.log("*** rsNotification module init");

    var rsNotificationModule = angular.module('rsNotification', ['rsMessenger']);

    var NotificationController = ['$log', '$scope', 'MessengerService', function ($log, $scope, MessengerService) {

        console.log("*** NotificationController init", $scope);
        $scope.badgeCount = 0;

        $scope.$on('rsMQTT.message', function (event, message) {
            $scope.badgeCount++;
            MessengerService.post(message.toString());
        });
    }];

    rsNotificationModule.directive('rsNotification', function () {
        console.log("*** Loading template");
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'templates/rs-notification.html',
            controller: NotificationController
        };
    });

})(angular);
```

In **app.js** I have the following configuration for *starter* module

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        url: "/app",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
        controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })
    .state('app.dashboard', {
        url: "/dashboard",
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: "templates/dashboard.html",
                controller: 'DashboardController'
            }
        }
    })

// if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/dashboard');
```

...and the directive **rs-notification.html**

```
<button class="button button-clear">
    <span class="fa fa-flag-o fa-2x"></span>
</button>
<span class="rs-badge danger" ng-show="badgeCount > 0">{{badgeCount}}</span>
```

The *rs-notification* directive is used in the *menu.html* template inside the *ionic-nav-bar*

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">

    <ion-side-menu-content>

        <ion-nav-bar class="rs-header">
            <ion-nav-back-button>
            </ion-nav-back-button>

            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon color-primary-light" menu-toggle="left"></button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>

            <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
                <div>
                    <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="showCart()">
                        <span>{{cartName}}</span>
                        <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-2x color-primary-dark"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <rs-notification></rs-notification>
            </ion-nav-buttons>

        </ion-nav-bar>

        <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>

    </ion-side-menu-content>

    <!-- Left menu... -->

</ion-side-menus>
```

The problem is that ***rsMQTT.message* event is fired twice** for each upcoming message, as matter of fact the *NotificationController* is instatiated twice as you can see in the console log:

```
*** rsNotification module init
*** NotificationController init
*** NotificationController init
*** Loading template
```

Comment: I not sure it's a problem on your component, but maybe in a parent directive. Try to put your component at higher levels to see if it's the same outcome.

Comment: You're right @Werlang, that it happens only when I put _rs-notification_ inside _ion-nav-buttons_!

Comment: I'd report as a bug to Ionic team (if you haven't already)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content of `ion-nav-buttons` element is [recompiled](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/af1bfef327e685585244c6051c4d38b98aa6c62a/js/angular/directive/navButtons.js) into another element and then injected into `$ionViewController`. Because of that, it is possible that your directive is in fact compiled (and the controller is instantiated) twice (or more). To get around that, you should move your logic into a service and leave that element as a nutshell only.